# Batch converting files with C# .NET

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

In the code snippet below, I am requesting the user to input their directory path to target their .pdf file to be converted. However, I would like to be able to convert a batch of .pdf files at once. How could I go about doing this? Say the user has 100 .pdf files in the directory path each with different file names. What is the best way to alter my code to be able to batch convert all the .pdf files at once?

```
        Console.WriteLine("PDF to Excel conversion requires a user directory path");
        Console.WriteLine(@"c:\Users\username\Desktop\FolderName\FileName.pdf");
        Console.WriteLine("Your Directory Path: ");
        var userPath = Console.ReadLine();

        string pathToPdf = userPath;

        string pathToExcel = Path.ChangeExtension(pathToPdf, ".xls");

        // Converting PDF to Excel file
        SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

        // 'true' = convert data to spreadsheet (tabular and textual)
        // 'false' = skip textual data and convert only tabular (tables) 
        f.ExcelOptions.ConvertNonTabularDataToSpreadsheet = true;

        // 'true' = preserve the original page layout
        // 'false' = place tables before text
        f.ExcelOptions.PreservePageLayout = true;

        f.OpenPdf(pathToPdf);

        if (f.PageCount > 0)
        {
            int result = f.ToExcel(pathToExcel);

            // open an excel workbook
            if (result == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToExcel);
            }
        }
```

Edit: Below you see my attempt to write the program using Bradley's Directory method shown below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome. I am Textron's PDF to Excel converter.");
        Console.WriteLine("\n - Create a folder with all your .pdf files to be converted");
        Console.WriteLine("\n - You must define your directory path");
        Console.WriteLine(@"   For Example ==> c:\Users\Username\Desktop\YourFolder");
        Console.WriteLine("\n Your directory: ");
        var userPath = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(userPath, "*.pdf"))
        {
            string excelPath = Path.ChangeExtension(userPath, ".xls");

            // Converting PDF to Excel filetype
            SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();

            // 'true' = convert data to spreadsheet (tabular and textual)
            // 'false' = skip textual data and convert only tabular (tables) 
            f.ExcelOptions.ConvertNonTabularDataToSpreadsheet = true;

            f.OpenPdf(userPath);

            if (f.PageCount > 0)
            {
                int result = f.ToExcel(excelPath);

                // open an excel workbook
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(excelPath);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all files in a directory use `Directory.EnumerateFiles`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)). In your case:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.pdf"))
{
    // PDF code, probably extracted to its own method!
}
```

In this *specific* case `GetFiles` would also work, but `EnumerateFiles` is better if you only want to do a subset; as it lazily evaluates.

Comment: I have implemented this in my code but it does not run as expected, I've plopped all my pdf code inside the foreach block and my 'directoryPath' variable is correctly defined by the user (which is me testing the program)

Comment: @Andre You'll have to be more specific than "It doesn't work"

Comment: see my edit above. In my original version, execution of the program would open excel and spit out a .xlx file

Comment: @Andre You keep using `userPath` inside the loop; those should probably be `file`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I needed to use the local variable as you suggested. Got the program working for batch conversion now.

Comment: @Andre Great! That's one reason I recommended extracting to a method. Harder to make that mistake